# javascript : submit page onload

Tags: javascript, html, servlets

I have one signin page in which I can signin with username and password.Now I want to submit this page in the background.Like if user hit one url then user dont see signin page but its directly login ( hardcode credential as of now ) and see next page.

so in servlet response i am sending html / js so that browser send the http request with username and password.

```
      out.println("<body onload=\"submitForm()\"><form action=\""
              + rmHost
              + "/abc/signin method=\"post\">");
      out.println("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"username\" value=\""
              + username + "\" ><br>");
      out.println("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"password\" value=\""
              + password + "\"><br>");
      out.println("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"location\" value=\"\">");
      out.println("</form> </body>
```

Using above code but browser is not send http post request to url.Is the above code correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the submit function of your form from js when body is loaded like this

`document.getElementById('form-id').submit();` //form-id is the id of your form

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

If You are using jQuery You can do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#formID').submit();
});
```

it's a way better than using 'onload=\"submitForm()' - this method is depricated.